# Incorrectly applied textures

Tags: lwjgl, blender, texture-mapping

I'm kinda new to this, so I'm stumped. 
I create a simple model of a card in blender with a single face and texture, then export it as .obj when I load it to lwjgl the texture is not only backwards but also applied incorrectly.

[image: original]

The texture coordinates in the obj file should be correct(even if I rounded them down to 0 and up to 1), but as you can see...

```
# Blender v2.67 (sub 0) OBJ File: ''
# www.blender.org
mtllib x.mtl
o Plane
v 0.5 0.000000 1.000000
v -0.5 0.000000 1.000000
v 0.5 0.000000 -1.000000
v -0.5 0.000000 -1.000000
vt 0 0
vt 1 0
vt 1 1
vt 0 1
vn 0.000000 1.000000 -0.000000
usemtl Material.002
s off
f 2/1/1 1/2/1 3/3/1
f 4/4/1 2/1/1 3/3/1
```

[image: edited]

Now i manually adjusted the coordinates and they seem to work, but it's till backwards.

```
# Blender v2.67 (sub 0) OBJ File: ''
# www.blender.org
mtllib x.mtl
o Plane
v 0.5 0.000000 1.000000
v -0.5 0.000000 1.000000
v 0.5 0.000000 -1.000000
v -0.5 0.000000 -1.000000
vt 0 0
vt 0.78 0
vt 0.78 0.585
vt 0 0.585
vn 0.000000 1.000000 -0.000000
usemtl Material.002
s off
f 2/1/1 1/2/1 3/3/1
f 4/4/1 2/1/1 3/3/1
```

Is the problem on the blender side(I set stuff wrong there) or lwjgl(I set other stuff wrong there)? Though I seem to have similar problem with models made by other people. BTW I'm currently using Slick to load the textures(but other methods resulted in the same bug).

[image: other]

This last textured model was made and imported basically the same way, but the texture seams to be correctly applied... it's upside down though. Actually all the textures are applied upside down not 'mirrored' left-to-right.

**UPDATE 1**

It's weird... did a little experiment and found some weird results. Textures:
512x512: OK,
1024x1024: OK,
1024x512: OK,
512x1024: OK,
512x256: OK,
256x512: OK, 
800x600: WRONG,
600x800: WRONG.
So magnitudes of 2(hope it's the correct term) work. I read that textures for slick/lwjgl have to have dimensions dividable by 2(even remember why), but why are the coordinates applied wrongly at certain dimensions?

Tried different order of coordinates... texture still upside-down(or sideways). And if I import the obj file back to blender go into edit mode and unwrap the textured face... it flips upside-down in there too.

**UPDATE 2**

As I understand, this is how texture coordinates should work:

[image: wright]

Somehow I get this:

[image: wrong]

Am I correct? This problem hinders my awesome game-making. The texture dimensions problem is still on the table too.  Please help.

**UPDATE 3**

Thanks to neomonkeus the upside-down texture problem is fixed. How about the texture dimension problem? Is there a "glTexParameteri()" command that would fix it? Ore is there something wrong with the texture matrix?

Comment: Think that you just need to negate the v component of the texture(u,v) -> (u, -v).

Comment: If you mean change: 1,1 0,1 0,0 1,0 to 1,-1 0,-1 0,0 1,0... it doesn't work. It seams to make the texture go out of bounds of the face.

Comment: Sorry should have said 1-v since they are normalised.

Comment: This fixes the upside-down problem. Thanks! How about the dimension problems?

Answer (score 0):

I'm stupid. It's the power of 2 thing. A question already asked and answered thoroughly. The weird thing is, that at some point the textures were scaled correctly... I just don't remember the method I used to load them. While the upside-down thing can be fixed by the '1-v' method, it shouldn't even appear when I basically copy-paste the code from www.lwjgl.org.

**EDIT**

Once again, I'm stupid. If you do glOrtho(0,800,600,0,1,-1) the texture will be flipped again, so wright-side up. Basically this was not only a stupid question, but an old and basic one as well. Just to make it clear... If I want to have the textures oriented the same way in perspective and orthographic view, I have to have 0.0 in the lower-left corner, wright?

BTW: slicks TextureLoader.getTexture(...) flipped param should flip the image on load, but I get the same result for true and false. What's up with that?